# Azure Logic App HTTP Post build JSON with Dynamic Variables

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I can't figure out how to build the JSON for an HTTP Post:

ie, this doesn't work where [somevariablehere].  How do I manually concat what I want to post along with some dynamnic variables?

```
{
  "color": "green", 
  "message": "(awesome) [somevariablehere]   ", 
  "notify": false, 
  "message_format": "text"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at documentation of the Logic Apps definition language:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language

You can use the `concat` function to concatenate strings, for example

```
{
  "color": "green", 
  "message": "@concat('awesome', actionBody('otherAction').someProperty)", 
  "notify": false, 
  "message_format": "text"
}
```

Comment: I realized I didn't need to concat anything but the docs helped: `  "(okay)  @{body('Step_2')?['score']}:  @{triggerBody()?['Text']} "`

Comment: @lucuma yes, you can use string interpolation as an alternative to using concat (but they are effectively one an the same). glad to hear you were able to get your expression working.